# nodejs why can not remove element with filter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of elements in a `notes.json` file, and I am having trouble removing them with the `filter` method.

Here's the how I read the notes from the json file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const p = path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),"data","notes.json");

// this function help me do fast code
const fastFunction = cb => {fs.readFile(p, (err, data) => {if (err) {return cb([]);} else {return cb(JSON.parse(data));}});};
```

I'm using this `fastFunction` inside another, `removeById`, like this:

```
static removeById(id) {fastFunction(notes => {const deleteNote = notes.filter(n => n.id !== id);fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(deleteNote), err => {if (err) {console.log(`Your Error Is: ${err}`);}});});}
```

And finally here's how I try to use the `removeById` function.

```
// here i used the function
const postDeleteNotes = (req, res, next) => {
  const myId = req.body.removeById;Note.removeById(myId);res.redirect("/admin");
};
```

But if I remove the note and try to get them again, it is still there.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: the function is not deleting, i wanted to delete the element is been clicked but it is returning the same result

Comment: Thanks, but I've meant, add it to your question, it will help people who want to help.

Comment: where? do you mean in the title

Comment: No, in the description. You only have a single code block, and the then you have your questions and explanations as comments in that code block. It is not easily read and understood, so potential answerers have trouble understanding what you want. Take a look at the FAQ, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No one knows what you want to do here. Put more details what do you need help with in the content of the question.

Comment: @JigSaw I've edited the question to try and make it clearer. What is now missing is twoi things: 1) how do you read the notes? The whole file or a bit more then just request might be relevant because you might be caching a `require` call. and 2) what do you see in `notes.json` after a successful delete call?

Comment: wow how did you edited so perfect, in notes.json there is the id and the notes and the book cover and the description,

Comment: the problem if i do this!
const deleteNote = notes.filter(n => { n.id !== id; }); 
// when i click everything is been deleting
but when i do this nothing happend
const deleteNote = notes.filter(n => n.id !== id; ); // everything stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a stranger solution here:

> i change this: `n => n.id !== id`
>   to this: `n => n.id != id`

Comment: can any one of you guys explain why this can be a solution because most of my time i remove things with filter as `!===` without using this weird solution `!=`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments I take it your code does something like this:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(arr.filter(i => i < 3 || i > 5));

// [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

but then looking back at `arr[4]` gives 5 because the `filter` function does **not** affect the original array. Instead **returns** the modified array. Therefore if you wanted to modify the original array, you would need to do an assignment.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
arr = arr.filter(i => i < 3 || i > 5);
```

Comment: no man is not like this let's say that this is notes.json 
`[{"id":0.9183098316482374,"note":"ghgh", "book cover": "never mind", "description": "again never mind"}, {a lot that you don't care about!}]`
but i have found answer just about 5mn can you explain it!